# how can I get facebook official page id of a page using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

for example the official page of `burj khalifa` is `https://www.facebook.com/BurjKhalifa/` where `BurjKhalifa` is the page id and alternate page id is `10262742980397`...

`https://www.facebook.com/10262742980397` and `https://www.facebook.com/BurjKhalifa/` refers to the official page of Burj Khalifa.. How can I get official facebook page id of a given place using `graph api`

Comment: All you have to do is make an API request for the page name, `/BurjKhalifa` …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generate and encode url of the page and call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FBurjKhalifa&access_token=[TOKEN]"
```

Comment: Nice, even works the other way around

$ oksocial 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?id=102627429803979&fields=link'


{
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/BurjKhalifa/",
  "id": "102627429803979"
}